# Adding attribute in database which is added in datamodel in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, core-data

I created one data model which consists of 10 entities.After few days, in one of that entity I added an attribute. At this time when i run the app, the app was crashed. So, Kindly help me to resolve this issue.
                     Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your code. At which point your app is crashing. Have you tried to solve it using break points ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After changing the model you have to delete your app on device/simulator and reinstall. That's because your existing SQLite-DB doesn't fit to the now changed model anymore.

Comment: false. You must create a new model version and create any extra entities/attributes in it.

Comment: Sure, that would be a better solution, especially for already rolled out apps. I assume that's not the case here.

Comment: IMO it's about doing the right thing right from the start, and not when it's needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're still just developing the app, the simplest answer is just to delete and re-install it.

If you really want to keep the contents of the database, Core Data can automatically migrate from one version of your schema to another (with certain caveats). [See the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html) for the details.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your app to crash - each time you need to add an attribute to an entity or an entity to a model - you must create new model version and show the managed object model to use that new version.

You can create new model version by going to: `Editor -> Add Model version...`. Afterwards enable **automigration** in `persistentStoreCoordinator` method of your app delegate:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSURL *storeURL = <#The URL of a persistent store#>;
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = <#The coordinator#>;
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
    [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

BOOL success = [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:<#Store type#>
                    configuration:<#Configuration or nil#> URL:storeURL
                    options:options error:&error];
if (!success) {
    // Handle the error.
}
```

Comment: That seems like overkill while you're developing an app.

Comment: IMO it's about doing the right thing right from the start, and not when it's needed.

Answer (score -1):

You have to make the app clean all targets and then build and also delete app from the simulator and then build the app

Comment: false. You must create a new model version and create any extra entities/attributes in it.